# Access denied on single file with explicit permissions set

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, access-control-list, ntfs, icacls

I have a Windows 2008R2 server that has a weird permissions issue.  I have a single file in a share that has inheritance disabled and explicit permissions set on the file.  The only groups that have entries listed in the security tab for the file are ADMINISTRATORS, SYSTEM, and the group with the users that should be accessing this file.  All three entries are full access with no deny permissions set.

All appropriate users are able to open the files as expected, but only users with permission to write in the parent directory are able to save to the file,   even though the inheritance is disabled and the parent directory write access group is not listed at all in the ACL. Other users that do not have permission to save to the parent directory are denied, even if they have full control permission specifically listed for their user.  This happens over the network as well as when logged into the server directly.

Users experiencing this issue can save a copy of the file to their desktop and then overwrite the network file fine, so they do have some form of write access.  They can change the permissions on the file as well.  I can have an affected user take ownership of the file and rewrite the permissions, but when we try to test access by renaming the file they get an error that they need permission from themselves.

I have run chkdsk /f on the volume, updated and rebooted the server, and recreated the ACL for the file in question with Explorer and ICACLS, all without luck.  Thank you in advance for any assistance resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was never able to get this to work properly by adding explicit NTFS permissions to a single file. The file was definitely inheriting some permissions, even though i told it not to and the inherited group was not listed in the ACL.
However, I did find a workaround.  If i create a subdirectory and remove inheritance and add the explicit permissions to that directory and then allow inheritance to the child items, it works as expected. I think this may be a bug in NTFS that Microsoft may end up needing to fix.